# Set a dedicated GPU for a virtual machine running Ubuntu

Tags: virtual-machine, nvidia-graphics-card, gaming

I am planning on buy a 1080ti sli for gaming and a titan v for machine learning in a virtual machine running ubuntu.

My question is can I set the titan v to run only on the VM and the 1080s on the normal desktop seeing as their best suited for gaming and the titan v is better made for machine learning?

Additionally would it be possible to run both types of GPUs at the same time where the 1080s support the titan v in ML and vice versa for gaming?

Thanks

Comment: SLI setups for Nvidia are only supported for the same types of cards as far as I know. You might still be able to use one of them for PhysX but that isn't going to get you much of a performance benefit.  It's unclear what your host OS would be and what virtualization solution you'd like to use. With the information you have provided it's likely that it's possible in some configuration.

Comment: So would it be possible to set the 1080s for Windows and have only the titan v run in the VM? What would happen if I just installed the 2 types of graphics cards without tinkering with any settings?

Comment: Just as a note SLI already only provides a very minor performance boost. So just going with a single 1080Ti would probably be sufficient. This would also (likely, depending on the motherboard) give each card more bandwidth. Though I'm not certain how much bandwidth ML needs. Again the answer is probably as you still haven't specified what virtualization solution you're looking at. Using Hyper-V, VirtualBox, VMware or something different is going to behave wildly differently. Have a look at the documentation and look for device passthrough options.

Comment: Using a PCI(e) card only in a VM and not in the host OS is quite possible. But most of the time it is NOT trivial to set up and switching to use both in the same OS probably will require a reboot os both guest and host. (So no trivial switching between using it in a guest, trying SLI or even just PhysX on one card and the other for rendering. Instead uou'll end up with one card in each OS).

Comment: @Hennes that's perfectly fine. In fact that's what I want! To have the titan v work on only the VM and 1080 to only work on the host since there's no point in using the titan v for rendering. Could you point me to a solution like software or ubuntu/virtual machine options? Thanks

Comment: @Matt.C No, not fine and here's why (sorry for being so blunt): If you need to ask you aren't qualified for the task. Whilst using a common virtualization software like Virtualbox with the standard settings it relatively easy to grasp, the kind of virtualization required to use different graphics cards independently is very hard and most experienced Linux user wouldn't even know where to start.  *NOT trivial to set up* is quite an understatement.

Comment: Oh ok, my bad. I must have misunderstood you. Thanks anyway

Comment: This link is from 2014, but it might offer a useful starting position:  https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/Multiheaded-NVIDIA-Gaming-using-Ubuntu-14-04-KVM-585/    Pleae note the part where they mention that *the video card itself needs to actually support PCI passthrough*. This is not true for every card and esp. Nvidia seems to have removed it from their consumer cards.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you have an x299 or x399 chipset providing the available PCI lanes TR4 has 64, x16 lanes per GPU would be required for full speed on the VM, Threadripper is a good option will give x16 lanes to each of the cards, if you dedicate the titan to the VM it should in theory come off of the host device list and be on the VM Client device list.  that would use x48 lanes leaving x16 lanes for m.2 NVMe SSDs network cards etc, a 16 core 32 thread CPU you should be able to split of the processing threads maybe use 16 to the VM Client, and keep 16 for the main system, a USB card would also be handy so you can connect seperates Keyboard, Mouse, and a USB audio adapter, I've been planning on a PC to be able to run 2 Gaming systems from one motherboard, the host will have its own NVMe SSD, and another NVMe SSD will be used as the VM install location so the VM will run off of that.  If you put 2 1080ti in without the bridge each GPU should be independent of each other instead of working as one.

Blue Diamond USB Audio adapter can allocate a Audio and Mic jack to a single USB slot so you can just allocate that USB device to the VM its about 15$ and it provides the 7.1 Virtual Surround sound, essentially its an external sound card, another option is just using a USB headset without the 3.5mm jack